# Will my iOS chat app get rejected from the app store due to NodeJs Server?

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku, encryption, firebase

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, sorry if its not, i would to know where the right place is.

I created a chat app that uses *firebase* and a `nodejs` server hosted on `heroku`

The messages are stored in firebase and are not encrypted.
The `nodejs` server is not very secure, i have passport `authentication`, but data is not encrypted or secure.

What is apple's policy on servers and not encrypted content. i tried looking around and couldnt find any useful content.

I just need to be pointed in the *right direction*.

Comment: Try to check the documentations and App Store Review Guidelines out but I don't think that this should be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the data stored on your device locally is protected and encrypted following the Apple guidelines. Your app needs to communicate with your servers over HTTPS layer as per the requirements of apple policy.

There is no policy for security on your backend servers. However it's always a good practice to keep your data stored securely and encrypted at server level. Passport authentication is good to make sure that your app will server data to the authenticated users only.

You can make your web-services (nodejs server) secured using various security options (oAuth, basic authentication, custom authentication, etc.)

Apple will not reject if your server is not secured.